# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_post()

Tags: forms, wp-insert-post

So I have a form that has makes the action jump to another php page.

There my php code tries to upload a post. I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_insert_post()

PHP Code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "upload_ugc") {

if($_POST["editindication"] == 'newpost'){
$post_array = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST["post_title"],
    'post_content'  => '',
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_array, true );
}
```

Comment: So what is actually the question? IMO the error says it all....

Comment: Why can't i use the function you think?

Comment: because you haven't included the file in which it is defined. To make things easier, please edit the question and explain what is it that you are actually trying to do. I guess it is AJAX, but better to hear it from you

Comment: Oh i see, i'll try and search which file that is! If you know, feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: hmm, I have updated my previous comment, please read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use WordPress functions inside your naked PHP file, you'll have to load the WordPress environment:

```
require_once '/path/to/wp-load.php';
```

That said it's best practice to NOT handle things via separate PHP files like that outside of WordPress, but use a plugin instead and fire your code on an appropriate action. You can use a page template or a shortcode to render your form, and then catch the form input on the `init` or `template_redirect` hook from within a plugin:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != 'upload_ugc' )
        return;

    // Your wp_insert_post statement
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/upload-success/' ) );
    die();
});
```

Also, when working with user input, don't forget about security, especially for logged in users. In your case you'll need a [wp_nonce_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) at least, and probably run your post title and content through [wp_kses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses).

Comment: So basically if I put what I want to do into a "plugin" I wouldn't need to `require_once '/path/to/wp-load.php';` Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Kovshenin, I tried adding the php that makes a post from my form as an plugin. But I'm not sure where to guide the "action" of the form now. I asked it here, if you have some spare time, it would be great if you could have a look! →http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222562/where-to-direct-the-action-of-a-form-with-a-custom-plugin-to-upload-a-post

Comment: If you're handling the form on init then pretty much any URL will do, for example `home_url( '/my-form/' );`

Comment: What do you mean by "handling the form on init" ?

Comment: I mean `add_action( 'init', function() { // form handler });`

Comment: I have `do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');` so you mean to say that that's not enough? Where shall I add the init function? Here's my full plugin code: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222562/where-to-direct-the-action-of-a-form-with-a-custom-plugin-to-upload-a-post

Comment: Sorry, but you're going to need to do some reading on actions and filters, the difference between `add_action` and `do_action`, core actions vs. custom actions, etc. Also, if you're going to do AJAX with admin-ajax.php, here's the right way to do it: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I read it but I'm still confused how to connect my form to my post-uploader-plugin...

I know I can use `add_action` to add functionality to the existing options, but I need to use `do_action` to actually make the post upload. So how can I trigger this `do_action` function I have in my plugin php file when the form on a page is submitted? Do I write the plugin php file path in the form's action?

Comment: You don't have to trigger init with `do_action`, WordPress does that automatically during initialization.

Comment: I think i got it. What you mean to say is: in case of a plugin with `do_action`, it only gets triggered once so its better to use `add_action` and add extra functions when uploading wordpress posts. So do you think it's better to just redirect the form to a seperate php that uses `do_action` and uploads the post, not from a plugin?

Comment: Because i can't find the way to "trigger my `do_action` when the user presses submit on the form"